# Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one. I have set QueryClient?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have wrapped `<ReactQueryDevtools />` in `<QueryClientProvider>`, so I don't understand why I am experiencing this issue?

I have looked at the TanStack Query documentation, & I don't understand the issue.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { worker } from '@uidotdev/react-query-api';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 100))
  .then(() =>
    worker.start({
      quiet: true,
      onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass',
    })
  )
  .then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="container">
              <App />
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
          <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
```

My console:

```
Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
```

Comment: What's the version of `react-query`?

Comment: The worker uses react-query? As the react query provider is only set after the worker is called, the worker will not have access to the query client?

Answer (score 8):

one of the imports is incorrect

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
```

should be

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following import was incorrect:

```
import {useQuery} from '@tanstack/react-query/build/modern'
```

The correct import is the following:

```
import {useQuery} from '@tanstack/react-query'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version. Use the following

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
```